# Drive cycle procedure for a 2001 Hyundai Accent

Tags: hyundai, cel, accent, evap

I have 2001 Hyundai Accent L 1.5 liter, 4 speed stick shift. The Check Engine light is on. The code that is coming up is "EVAP under lean P1128 Fuel Trim Lean". All other monitors are good.

I need to get the car registered immediately. How do I run a drive cycle on this car? The only procedure I can find is for a automatic transmission. What else do I need to fix the CEL code?

Comment: You mention drive cycles ... unfortunately you aren't going to get this through the drive cycles before tomorrow even if you do get the problem fixed. It usually takes a couple of days to clear the cycles, though some vehicles have a specific drive cycle which can accomplish it faster. One of the issues is, the car must cool down between, so this lengthens the time.

Answer (score 1):

P1128 code tells you that the engine is running too weak under steady cruising when the EVAP system is checked by the ECU. You need to have an EVAP test to make sure where the fault lies. The fuel tank cap, EVAP vent, purge valves, O2 sensor, exhaust leak, MAP sensor and MAF sensor can all 'fool' the ECU into this code. Remember that the fault codes are what the ECU computes to be wrong, you still have to check the systems over for correct operation. The ECU can compute to 'EVAP fault' because of a faulty component such as the MAF, for example, but still have the MAF pass its monitor.

Comment: Thank You Allan, Your and Paulsters  answers have helped ALOT! Now to find a shop that can help.